# How to add a rule to topology in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, topology, error-000732

Looks like I have the same problem as [Anthony](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/156973/how-to-add-rule-and-add-feature-class-to-topology-using-arcpy-and-stop-getting-e), but it seems like I have a bit more information to it.

--> Running ArcGIS 10.4.1

```
import os
import arcpy
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = 'TRUE'
gdb = r'F:\path\to\gdb\database.gdb'
fd = 'check_geometries'
fc = 'geometries'
topo = 'geometries_topology'
arcpy.env.workspace = gdb
arcpy.CreateTopology_management(fd, topo)
topo_path = os.path.join(gdb, fd, topo)
fc_path = os.path.join(gdb, fd, fc)
arcpy.ValidateTopology_management(topo_path)
arcpy.AddRuleToTopology_management(topo_path, "Must Not Intersect (Line)", fc_path)
```

The error code I am getting here is continuously 000732.

```
File "C:\APPS\ArcGIS\Desktop10.4\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 16214, in AddRuleToTopology
raise e
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000732: Input Feature class: Dataset   does not exist or is not supported
Failed to execute (AddRuleToTopology).
```

Strange enough, the same dataset is used to create the topology in the first place. I am using the name of the feature class to create the topology and the complete path of the topology to add the rule because it was failing before, when only giving the name, and I read that it requires the full path.

Would also be great if ESRI would get that consistant...

In addition to the earlier referenced posting I added the ValidateTopology function, which runs through without any problem. Still, adding a rule to the topology is impossible.

I can see the error is raised in line 16214 in the management.py file. Since I went step by step through the process I was able to confirm that all paths went correct through the gp_fixargs() function, and optional argument not given have been also correctly taken of the arguments list.

I assume the process is failing in the subsequent run of gp.AddRuleToTopology_management().

--> AddRuleToTopology

```
16208   from arcpy.geoprocessing._base import gp, gp_fixargs
16209   from arcpy.arcobjects.arcobjectconversion import convertArcObjectToPythonObject
16210   try:
16211       retval = convertArcObjectToPythonObject(gp.AddRuleToTopology_management(*gp_fixargs((in_topology, rule_type, in_featureclass, subtype, in_featureclass2, subtype2), True)))
16212       return retval
16213   except Exception, e:
16214       raise e
```

Can someone tell me on how to get a rule added to my topology?

Comment: i didn't check, but I think that you first need AddFeatureClassToTopology_management (in_topology, in_featureclass, xy_rank, z_rank)

Comment: You are absolutely correct! CreateTopology_management is based on a feature dataset...